# Can I find an element which is at the inside a table in Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I need to find an element that is present inside a table.

Eg:
The question is very simple, can I mark my own google calendar from 3pm to 4pm tomorrow using a Selenium script?

Comment: Please provide a specific example.

Comment: "Intersection of column X and row Y" does not exist. Look at the DOM. All you have is Y-th td element inside X-th tr element.

Comment: @PeterMasiar Yes that is  true, how do I work with it?

Comment: read up on loops

Comment: Got this - http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/selenium-tutorial-18/ - solved my problem. Thanks all

Comment: Can you answer your own question and accept it the next day?

Answer (score 0):

Provide CSS row and column identifiers.
For example if 5 table rows have the same class and 3 table columns have the same class but only 1 column-row combination cell is unique then use identifiers such as

```
table.row_class.column_class
```

or

```
table tr.some_row_class td.some_column_class`
```

etc.

I don't understand the 'two tables' requirement however so I may not be understanding your question.  A detailed example would help.

Answer (score 0):

This was a table which had a table inside it. I used loops to read in all rows in a table into a list of WebElement type. Iterated through this list size to have all columns in each row. Now I have all elements in the table on which I can perform any action intended. This is why @Peter Masiar asked me to read up on loops. Below is how one can do this.

```
WebElement htmltable=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[1]/tbody"));

List<WebElement> rows=htmltable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for(int rnum=0;rnum<rows.size();rnum++)

{

    List<WebElement> columns=rows.get(rnum).findElements(By.tagName("th"));

    System.out.println("Number of columns:"+columns.size());

    for(int cnum=0;cnum<columns.size();cnum++)

    {

        System.out.println(columns.get(cnum).getText());

    }

}
```

Comment: Is this answer or question ?

Comment: This is the answer. @Sagar007

Comment: I would not write loops to get at an element when I can use the css or xpath to get it, which I can if it is in the DOM

Comment: Would it work even if it is inside a table? I tried getting the same element using xpath - didn't work. Can you please elaborate?